# how to give first column as empty and second column contains button in TableLayout in android

Tags: android

I am designing a login page which has `EditText` and `TextView` for username & password and buttons for sign-in & reset. I need to place my buttons in a single column so that the first column should be empty and second column should have 2 buttons. Can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

This is my xml code.

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/con1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25pt"
    android:layout_marginRight="25pt"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent" android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_heading"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="76px"
        android:layout_y="24px"
        android:text="SignIn Here"
        android:gravity="center" 
      >
    </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_username"
        android:layout_width="20pt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="19px"
        android:layout_y="57px"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Username" 
          android:layout_weight="0.5">

    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_username"
        android:layout_width="20pt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="54px"
        android:layout_y="80px"
        android:textSize="18sp" 
          android:layout_weight="0.5">
    </EditText>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_password"
        android:layout_width="20pt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="21px"
        android:layout_y="131px"
        android:text="Password" 
          android:layout_weight="0.5">
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_password"
        android:layout_width="20pt"
        android:layout_height="47px"
        android:layout_x="53px"
        android:layout_y="155px"
        android:password="true"
        android:textSize="18sp" 
          android:layout_weight="0.5">
    </EditText>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

    <LinearLayout >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_signin"
        android:layout_width="80pt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="52px"
        android:layout_y="200px"
        android:text="SignIn" 
          android:layout_weight="0.025">
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_reset"
        android:layout_width="80pt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="123dp"
        android:layout_y="201px"
        android:text="Reset" 
          android:layout_weight="0.025">
    </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: is it compulsory to left one row blank. because this space can be handled with margin

Comment: Can you provide an image of your requirement ??? While in your case you can simply use one `Relative Layout` to get that kind of UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 <TableLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/con1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25pt"
    android:layout_marginRight="25pt"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_heading"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="76px"
        android:layout_y="24px"
        android:text="SignIn Here"
        android:gravity="center" 
      >
    </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_username"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_x="19px"
        android:layout_y="57px"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Username" >

    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_username"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_x="54px"
        android:layout_y="80px"
        android:textSize="18sp" >

    </EditText>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_password"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_x="21px"
        android:layout_y="131px"
        android:text="Password" >

    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_password"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="47px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_x="53px"
        android:layout_y="155px"
        android:password="true"
        android:textSize="18sp" >

    </EditText>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_signin"
        android:layout_width="80pt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="52px"
        android:layout_y="200px"
        android:text="SignIn" 
          android:layout_weight="0.025">
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_reset"
        android:layout_width="80pt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="123dp"
        android:layout_y="201px"
        android:text="Reset" 
          android:layout_weight="0.025">
    </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you want to follow this shady logic, i suggest using

```
<Space/>
```

or

```
<android.support.v4.widget.Space>
```

The docs say

> Space is a lightweight View subclass that may be used to create gaps between components in general purpose layouts.

Comment: Use android:layout_column="1" instead this

Comment: @MaxF spot on. It's column="0" if first though?

Answer (score 4):

You can set column number with **android:layout_column** argument

```
<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:text="Save As..."
        android:padding="3dip" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Ctrl-Shift-S"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>
```